# How to configure Microsoft Bot Framework with Office365 Email?

Tags: office365, botframework

I have developed a very simple bot I want to connect with my [Office 365 Group](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-about-Office-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2).  Both are relatively new technologies so it's hard to find concrete information.

After creating and uploading my bot, I click Add to enable on email channel.
[image]

The Add screen then takes me to a "Configure Email" screen, which I'm not sure what to do about:
[image]

My questions are:

1. How do I configure my Bot with an email channel?
2. How would authentication work if I was to distribute this bot to other enterprises with their own Office365 service and active directory?
3. Since the bot is located on Azure, will it need any kind of access to the client's active directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you'll want to create a new Office365 account to represent your bot (i.e. MyBotName@SomeOfficeDomain.com).  All of your client's will use this same email address to communicate with the bot regardless of what domain they are on.  BotFramework does not yet support individual enterprise deployments.

Comment: Thanks, however I am unable to get the login to work.  We have our own AD which is connected with Office 365.  I have my account in our AD.  When I try to put in those credentials, I get the error "Unable to validate the given credentials."  I tried the following emails: mybot@companydomain.com and mybot@companydomain.onmicrosoft.com.  None have worked.  Thoughts?

Comment: An Office365 or Outlook.com account will work.  For your own AD, it depends on how you've set it up. BotFramework uses the EWS Api (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx).

Comment: Thank you I got an outlook.com email working, but not my AD account.  Also, would "Listen to all messages" checkbox apply to emails, or is it just for messaging groups like Slack?

Comment: You are correct, the "Listen to all messages" does not apply to email as the bot is addressed in the recipients list.  It only applies to group conversations in channels like Slack in which you may want the bot only to respond when addressed directly.

Comment: I finally got my exchange account to connect.  It just worked randomly.  However, when I send email to my exchange account the bot is not replying.  Is there any way to find what the error is, what's happening behind the scenes?

Comment: When you have a chance, can you look into http://stackoverflow.com/q/36614751/487940?  I have been unable to get much help on that.