# Microsoft Bot Framework: Bot not replying to email when using Exchange Email

Tags: office365, botframework

I have a simple bot uploaded to Azure.  I have configured an Email connector for my bot.  When I use an Outlook.com email, the bot would successfully replies to messages.  However, when I use a domain email to configure the connector, the bot does not reply to messages.

This leads me to believe that there is an issue somewhere in the bot connector, just not sure what it is.  Credentials were successfully validated on the Configure Email screen on the website, so that is not the issue.

My questions:

1. Is there any way to track down what the error might be?  What could the error be?
2. Also, what's a good practice to track errors that might be occurring in the bot?
3. Lastly, when deploying to Azure, are there any benefits to using the debug configuration vs release for development and tracking errors?

**Update** BotFramework Portal now shows status as "Error" but still no details on what the error is.
[image]

Comment: Please post your bot name so we can look up in the logs to resolve your issue.

Comment: My bot name is: "HB - AI Test Bot".

Comment: Looks like an authorization error attempting to connect to your server

Comment: @Lars Could the 401 be caused by a timeout? Validate Credentials is not working either. We are using Office365 for email.

Comment: Please send an email to bf-reports@microsoft.com so we can get some additional info.  Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hover over the "Error" status is will display what the specific error is.