# how to use email channel in microsoft bot builder

Tags: node.js, botframework

Currently i am using slack channel with bot builder. 
I want to use email channel, is there any sample code for this.
What is effective way to send email from bot to avoid spam 
I am using node js

Comment: What do you mean by sample code? Email is just another channel that you enable in the Bot Framework Dev portal.

Comment: Thanks for reply 
btw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36580770/how-to-configure-microsoft-bot-framework-with-office365-email helped me to understand some concept of email channel, but still i have some query

1)how send email back from bot 
2)does it support other email except outlook

Answer (score 1):

There's no extra code needed for the email channel.  Your bot will reply to the body of an email it receives. You can add things like [channel specific code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-channeldata#create-a-custom-email-message) if you like. Right now only office 365 emails will work, please read the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/channel-connect-email)

The bot will reply to an email sent to the registered email address with an email where the body is the same message that you would see as a response in other channels like slack, emulator, etc